# Having problem to use global styles in styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to use the GlobalStyle to set-up some configurations for my SAP. But i'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: 
  body {
    color: "white";
  }
```

My code (App.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import createGlobalStyle from 'styled-components';
import MainContainer from './Components/MainContainer';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: "white";
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <MainContainer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And in index.js, i'm using StrictMode:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the error was in the import of createGlobalStyle, the correct line is:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
```